# Get rid of "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error without using non-null assertion or optional chaining

Tags: typescript

I have the code like below

```
export type ConditionalItemType = [
  { condition: string },
  { [key: string]: FormItemDataType }
];
export type ConditionalItemDataType = ConditionalItemType[];

export type FormItemDataType = {
  required: boolean;
  type: string;
  constraint?: TextConstraintType;
  options?: string[];
  conditional?: ConditionalItemDataType;
};

export type TextConstraintType = {
  min?: number;
  max?: number;
  format?: string;
};

const obj: FormItemDataType = {
  required: true,
  type: 'select',
  options: ['simple', 'complicated'],
  conditional: [
    [
      { condition: 'complicated' },
      {
        'How Complicated': {
          required: true,
          type: 'text',
          constraint: {
            max: 30,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};

const func = (input: FormItemDataType) => {
  if ('conditional' in input) {
    input.conditional.filter((arrItem) => console.log(arrItem));
  } else null;
};
```

I am getting `'input.conditional' is possibly 'undefined'` error at `input.conditional.filter((arrItem) => console.log(arrItem))`.

How to get rid of this error? I cannot use `non-null assertion` or `optional chaining` . I cannot change the type either.

I thought I could do this by using "Type Guards" & I assume I am doing that at `if ('conditional' in input)` but apparently not. Can anyone help?

**Update**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the `in` operator and just check if the `input.conditional` is set, the classic way.

```ts
const func = (input: FormItemDataType) => {
  if(input.conditional) { //  tells TypeScript that input.conditional under this block must be set
    input.conditional.filter((arrItem) => console.log(arrItem));
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my actual code, this does not seem to be working (added a pic with the error) when I remove the `non-null assertion` or `optional chaining`, any idea what I am doing wrong there? I thought I replicated that error in the code I put in the question but apparently not (you answer works in code example that i put). Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be that your `formProps[item]` may be undefined, or `formProps` itself.

Comment: That are not. It is weird on to why I am getting this error. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. Although I recommend that you break up that nested ternary logic first. That can definitely help pinpoint the issue, not to mention make code more maintainable.